# What to return in RESTful api's GET methods?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm relatively new to REST, and I've had a question from the beginning.

I go straight to the point, let's say I have an e-commerce system, so I have some "products", I also have this resource: `/api/products/1234` in my web api and I send a GET HTTP request to it.

**What should it return?** If it returns the entire entity including all properties, it's not appropriate in the situations which I only need some of those properties and the others would be useless. For example, in some scenarios I just need the "Title" and "Price", so, I don't need other properties, it's just an overhead.

How to handle this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

I can think about two ways to handle it.

### Custom media type

You could use one of the following (or both) media types to retrieve a full representation of a product:

```
GET /api/products/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
```

```
GET /api/products/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/vnd.company.full+json
```

And the following media type to retrieve only the a short representation of the product:

```
GET /api/products/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/vnd.company.short+json
```

### Query string parameter

Alternatively, you could support selecting the fields to be retrieved with a query string parameter.

Use the following to retrieve the full representation of a product:

```
GET /api/products/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
```

And the following to retrieve only the the name and the price of the product:

```
GET /api/products/1?fields=name,price HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
```

For conveniece, despite the fields listed, you could always return the identifier of the product.

---

The approaches described above could also be applied to collections of resources, such as `/api/products`.

As pointed by Evert in the comments, *"it might be worth researching whether sending everything anyway really makes a dent in performance or bandwidth. It's sometimes a bit nicer to have fatter models for clarity if there's no significant cost."*

Going a bit further and quoting Donald Knuth: [*"premature optimization is the root of all evil"*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/122966). That is, the absence of *measured* performance issues you shouldn't optimize because you *think* you will get a performance gain. Some obvious optimizations can be performed but anything that isn't a trivially clear optimization should be avoided until it can be measured.

Comment: This is a great answer. I would add that it might be worth researching whether sending everything *anyway* really makes a dent in performance or bandwidth. It's sometimes a bit nicer to have fatter models for clarity if there's no significant cost.

Comment: While query parameters are for sure the easiest solution to tackle the issue, it also bears the danger of transfering implicit knowledge to the client. If the API provides all links with meaningful link-relation names and clients can sense the meaning when to invoke what it is sure a way to go. Media types on the contrary are a contract between servers and clients about the format exchanged that gives the data some sense and allows a peer to process the data correctly. According to fielding, however, it should be generic enough to be reusable. Content type negotiation is the driving force here

Comment: Fielding also mentioned that [clients shouldn't preassume that certain endpoints return certain types meaningful to the client](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) but instead rely on content type negotiation to receive data in a format it can actually handle (if supported by the server). The problem i.e. with `application/json` is, that it doesn't convey any semantical hints on the exchanged data but only its syntactical structure and how to parse it in general, besides lacking support for propper HATEOAS.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to keep in mind that `/api/products/1234` identifies a *resource*, not an *entity*.  Your API may have many different resources describing the same entity.  See Jim Webber's talk [REST: DDD In the Large](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc).

(Also note that there is a tradeoff, because each resource will have its own cache entry -- it may be awkward if the client modifies one resource, and then sees a stale copy of another resource describing the same entity).

If you go with the different resources approach, you can use any spelling variations in the URI that you like.  Query string is a common choice, or a file extension on the path segment, or even producing a separate path segment.  As far as I can tell, the only *real* distinction among the choices is whether or not [relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) (RFC 3986) has any value in your use case.

> *What should it return?*

A common choice is to use the [DataTransferObject](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) pattern.  Fowler writes

> When you're working with a remote interface, such as Remote Facade (388), each call to it is expensive. As a result you need to reduce the number of calls, and that means that you need to transfer more data with each call. One way to do this is to use lots of parameters. However, this is often awkward to program - indeed, it's often impossible with languages such as Java that return only a single value.
>
> The solution is to create a Data Transfer Object that can hold all the data for the call.

Because REST is "designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer" ([Fielding](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)), the approach is a decent fit.